# Does DocuSign Allow Setting Name/Email of the Sender?

Tags: docusignapi

The DocuSign account created is by an individual, but when using the DocuSign API to generate an envelope from a template and sending to a receiver, the name and email address of the account holder shows up instead of the company the user works for.

Is there a way to show company name and official company email instead of the account user's name/email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name and email address corresponding to the sending DocuSign user account will always be shown on/for sent envelopes. That being said, there's an easy way to achieve what you describe:

- Create another "user" (i.e., membership) within the same DocuSign account -- this will represent the "system sender" user account -- i.e., the user account that you'll specify when sending envelopes with the API.
- When creating the new "user", set name and email address to the values that you want to see/use for envelopes you send via the API.
- Make sure to grant the new "user" the appropriate API-related settings (under the **DocuSign API** heading when viewing *User Permissions*).
- Use the "system sender user" credentials to send envelopes via the API.

Keep in mind that when using this "system sender" user to send envelopes via the API, that user will be considered the sender of each envelope sent using that account's credentials -- which means that only that user's credentials can be used via the DocuSign web console to access the DocuSign envelope for viewing/correcting/etc.  Other members of that same DocuSign account won't be able to access the envelope via the DocuSign web console unless you explicitly grant 'folder sharing' rights between users.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but have been directed to look into the Branding feature. Is there a reason it couldn't solve this particular problem?

Comment: It seems like the Branding feature allows one to change the content of the email, including links to an email address or website. It doesn't seem to allow one to change the "From" address.